# For changing file folders in php what is the difference between /../ ./../ and ../?

Tags: php

For changing file folders what is the difference between

/../
./../
../ ?

Some includes won't work unless it is `include "/../filename.php";` while others will work just fine with `include "../filename.php;"`.

Comment: This is not a PHP question, it's an OS-level question (looks like Linux in this case).

Comment: ../ is moving into a directory one level up and ./ means file within same directory

Comment: I am using it specifically in PHP for the include command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathing 101:

Every running process has a "working directory". This is where any "relative" paths in file operations will be based from.

```
./          - current directory (the "working" directory)
../         - parent directory
../..       - grandparent directory
../foo      - brother/sister directory "foo"
../../foo   - uncle/aunt directory "foo"
```

There are also ABSOLUTE paths, which start at the ultimate ancestor of all directories - the root of the file system. On Unix-ish systems, that's `/`, on Windows systems, that'd be a drive letter, e.g. `C:\`

```
/            - ultimate starting directory - root of file system
/foo         - immediate child directory
/foo/bar     - grandchild directory
/foo/bar/baz - great-grandchild directory.
```

Combining these:

absolute+relative:

```
/foo/bar/../baz

   1. `/`     - start at root /
   2. `/foo`  - descend into 'foo' (now at `/foo`)
   3. `/bar`  - descent into 'bar' (now at `/foo/bar`)
   4. '../`   - go back a level  (back at `/foo`)
   5  `/baz   - descend into  'baz` (now at `/foo/baz`)
```

relative:

```
../foo/bar/../baz

  1. Start in current directory `./`
  2. `../` - ascend to parent (now at `../`)
  3. `foo/` - descend into sibling `foo` (now at `../foo`)
  4. `bar/` - descend into niece/nephew `bar` (now at `../foo/bar`)
  5. `../` - ascend back to sibling foo (now at `../foo`)
  6. `baz/` - descend into niece/nephew 'bar' (now at `../foo/baz`)
```

Basically, ANY path which starts with `/` or `c:\` is an absolute path, and any path starting with a `.` is a relative one. **EVERY** directory contains `.` and `..`, which are simply pointers to itself (`.`), and its parent (`..`). The parent is there so you don't need to know the name of your ancestor directory, you just need to know `..`.

Since directories contain a reference to themselves, something like `./././././.` is simply a very redundant way of saying "in the current directory".

Therefore `../foo/./bar` is no different than `../foo/bar`, because the `.`, being where it is, simply means "stay in the same place".

Comment: What's strange is that I am using a windows based systems, yet it matters so much! :)

Comment: Same thing holds for windows, other than changing slashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

1. ../--refers to previous dir from current dir
2. ../../--refers to 2 times previous from current dir

and so on..

Comment: And what about this  /../

Comment: Same as ../ i think.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where the path starts i.e. in same folder as the file or from root of the file system.

*/../*  will start the path from your hard-drive root

*./../*  and *../*  will start from current directory of the file.